# Dimension one graded algebra $R$ is a domain then $l(R_n)\leq 1$ for all $n$.

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-algebras

Let $R$ be a Noetherian positively graded $k$-algebra of dimension $1$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field. If length $l(R_n)=H (R, n) > 1$ for some $n$, show $R$ is not a domain.

I assume $R$ is a domain, then there exists a homogeneous element $x$ of degree $d$ such that we have the exact sequence
$0\longrightarrow R[-d]\stackrel{x}\longrightarrow R\longrightarrow R/(x)\longrightarrow0$. Therefore $H(R,n)+H(R/(x),n+d)=H(R,n+d)$. Since $\dim R/(x)=0$, $H(R,n)=l(R/(x))_n=0$ for $n\gg0$. I don't know if this is helpful and I am also not sure how to use the algebraically closed condition of the field.

Comment: As a starting hint: write $R=S/\mathfrak{p}$ where $S=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ with $\operatorname{deg}(x_i):=d_i>0$ and where $\mathfrak{p}$ is a homogeneous prime ideal of height $n-1$ in $S$. What does the fact that $k$ is algebraically closed tell you about minimal homogeneous generators of $\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: @metalspringpro Could you elaborate on this? Did you mean their factors?

Comment: I guess what I am thinking really only applies directly to the standard graded case. The point there is that, since $k$ is algebraically closed, we have access to Nullstellansatz, and $R$ is the coordinate ring of an (irreducible) projective variety of dimension $0$ so it is isomorphic to a polynomial ring.